# Update associative array key value in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know what's wrong with my code.

I'm trying to update qty value, but when I var_dump the data a second time, qty doesn't get updated / rewritten. What am I missing? what is the right approach?

```
$prod = 647bba344396e7c8170902bcf2e15551;
$qty = 2
var_dump($ordered);

array (size=2)
  '647bba344396e7c8170902bcf2e15551' => 
    array (size=7)
      'rowid' => string '647bba344396e7c8170902bcf2e15551' (length=32)
      'id' => string '545' (length=3)
      'qty' => string '415' (length=3)
      'price' => string '15.573770' (length=9)
      'teza' => string '0' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Pants 1' (length=14)
      'subtotal' => float 6463.11455
  'd64a340bcb633f536d56e51874281454' => 
    array (size=7)
      'rowid' => string 'd64a340bcb633f536d56e51874281454' (length=32)
      'id' => string '530' (length=3)
      'qty' => string '144' (length=3)
      'price' => string '17.213110' (length=9)
      'teza' => string '0' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Toys' (length=19)
      'subtotal' => float 2478.68784

            foreach ($ordered as $item) {
                if ($item['rowid'] == $prod)
                    $item['qty'] == $qty;
            }
         var_dump($ordered);      

array (size=2)
  '647bba344396e7c8170902bcf2e15551' => 
    array (size=7)
      'rowid' => string '647bba344396e7c8170902bcf2e15551' (length=32)
      'id' => string '545' (length=3)
      'qty' => string '415' (length=3)
      'price' => string '15.573770' (length=9)
      'teza' => string '0' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Pants white' (length=14)
      'subtotal' => float 6463.11455
  'd64a340bcb633f536d56e51874281454' => 
    array (size=7)
      'rowid' => string 'd64a340bcb633f536d56e51874281454' (length=32)
      'id' => string '530' (length=3)
      'qty' => string '144' (length=3)
      'price' => string '17.213110' (length=9)
      'teza' => string '0' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Pants black' (length=19)
      'subtotal' => float 2478.68784
```

Comment: I don't see where you set $ordered to anything. Did I miss that?

Comment: Suggested reading as well: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: Tnx! I will read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        foreach ($ordered as &$item) {  // Get array byref
            if ($item['rowid'] == $prod){
                $item['qty'] = $qty;  // Fixed evaluation
            }
        }

        var_dump($ordered);
```

Comment: Good job sir! :) this helped!

Answer (score 0):

`==` vs `=`

Looks like an evaluation when you want an assignment.

What does this do?

`$item['qty'] == $qty;`

Answer (score 0):

you have wrong in your

**php assignment operator and comparison operator**

```
=
```

as use to assign value(assign operator)

```
==
```

as use to compare values

```
    foreach ($ordered as $item) {
          if ($item['rowid'] == $prod)
              $item['qty'] = $qty;          

   }
```